PowerShell can't run cmlet on remote computer
Update: The problem has, shall we say, "auto corrected". Just now I ran the script and it didn't throw the "The term 'Get-OBAllRecoveryPoints' is not recognized" error for server2. Well, that's a relief, but I would prefer predictable rather than mysterious behavior.
I have a script that runs on a management server that uses Invoke-Command to get the time of the most recent Microsoft Azure Backup from a list of remote servers. It works for all but one server, and I can't figure out why it fails for that server.
Here's the relevant snippet of the script:
  $block = {
      return (Get-OBAllRecoveryPoints | Sort-Object -Property backuptime -Descending |select backuptime)[0].BackupTime 
  } 

 "server1","server2" | %{
      $mostRecent = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $block -ComputerName $_
 }

I'm running the script as a domain administrator on the management server. For server1 I get a date-time string, which is what I expect. For server2 I get:

The term 'Get-OBAllRecoveryPoints' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the  path is
correct and try again.

When I run 'Get-OBAllRecoveryPoints' on the desktop of server2 (logged in as the same user as the management server), I get the expected output (i.e., a list of backup recovery points).
As a work around, I wrote a script that contains the code of the script block shown above. It runs as expected when run on server2 (returns the date-time of latest backup). I figured I should be able to call that script in the script block of my original Invoke-command call in the script that runs on the management server, like this:
 $block = {

    C:\Users\administrator.abcdomain\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\Get-LastBackupTime.ps1
   
}

The Invoke-command returns the same error message (i.e., 'Get-OBAllRecoveryPoints' isn't available). Just to make sure that Invoke-Command is really calling the script, I change the script to return "abc", and that's what Invoke-Command returned.
I tried adding "import-module MSOnlineBackup" to the script block. It returns

The specified module 'MSOnlineBackup' was not loaded because no valid
module file was found in any module directory.

To summarize: The script I run on the management server returns the latest backup for all servers except one. For that one, it reports that the command and its module cannot be found. I can't reproduce this when I run the same commands locally on the server.
Any idea as to the problem or how I might figure it out from here?

Check the env:$PSModulePath variable when executing remotely. Also include the folder where the module is located. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-module?view=powershell-7.4

Now the script runs without error. I didn't change anything. Just happened to check and see that it was returning the date-time value I was expecting. Updated the original post.
